# Forward UIAlertView click to another cotroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I'm trying to send the user to another controller when they click the "OK" button on an UIAlertView but I'm getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***   setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: classname)'
```

My UIAertView is within an if statement like this:

```
if([placemarks count] > 0)
  {
    CLPlacemark *foundPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location set"
                       message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your location, was set to %@", foundPlacemark.country]
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [message show];

  }
```

I'm checking the button being clicked with:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 0)
{
    MasterViewController *controller=[[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  }
}
```

I do have the delegate set:

```
@interface LocationViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

The UIAlertView works fine on its own. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. You're trying to set a nil value for the key "classname". I don't see that anywhere in the code you posted, so I don't think the error is here. Have you set an exception breakpoint to see if it pinpoints the offending line?

Comment: Does your app crash when you click OK button?

Comment: @rdelmar the breakpoint doesn't show anything useful besides main.

Comment: @akiniwa Yes, it crashes when OK is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(buttonIndex == 0)
{
    // MasterViewController *controller=[[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
       MasterViewController *controller=[[MasterViewController alloc]init]; // creat your MasterViewController like this. 
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  }
}
```

if it is not crashing by coding like this , I think the problem is your IB

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Interface Builder to make the MasterViewController's UI? It seems there is something wrong with the MasterViewController's nib file. When the MasterViewController get init from the xib file, the setting is missing and you got a exception.

The most possible situation is there may be some bad connect between the xib file and the file owner. Please check if there any connected IBOutlet you deleted in your code but leaving the connection in the xib file. If so, delete the connect and it can be solved.

Comment: If I switch the code around and go straight to Master and don't use the LocationController everything works fine.

Comment: Looks like you were right. It works with just init, now to track down the prob. Thanks.